# ender.js install fails

Tags: javascript, ender

I'm trying to install ender.js.
I've run the following command

```
 sudo npm install ender -g
```

but after the install (with no error), I can't access ender command line.
I have the latest node and npm install (via brew)

anybody ran into this problem?

Comment: Does you path include the install folder for npm modules?

Comment: Not completely sure about how i should do that. I have bower and yeoman installed via npm (without sudo) and they work fine. Ender require sudo install but seems to install in `/usr/local/share/npm/bin/ender`. I have added this to my path but to no avail.

Comment: I was having something similar with node modules. In my case, adding ``/usr/local/share/npm/bin`` to my $PATH resolved the issue. When you ``echo $PATH`` do you see other node-related entries there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to add `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` to your path.

Try adding the following line to your bash profile (in `~/.profile`, or `~/.bashrc`, etc.):

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
```

Then source the file to your current environment with `. ~/.profile`. And that should fix your issue.

Going forward, I would recommend using [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage your node versions, and npm installs.